# Issue with HttpUtility.HtmlEncode with other language characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, encoding

I was trying to encode the HTML special characters like ', ", <,> etc with HttpUtility.HtmlEncode. But I noticed this is also encoding french characters like (é) to é and now  é is getting displayed as it is on my HTML page. I don't want this I just want to encode ', ", <,> and few other characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should those characters look differently? Why is it a problem if they are replaced? This is by design. You can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853920/c-sharp-htmlencode-iso-8859-1-entity-names-vs-numbers) question to see longer discussion. Unless your users can't properly see text you are displaying, you shouldn't mess with this, for security/compatibility reasons.

`HtmlUtility` seems to encode several classes of characters, among which [ISO-8859-1 character set](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp)
If you still don't want a specific character to be encoded, you are forced to use `string.Replace()` for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The various .NET text encoding functions are notorious for being badly documented and doing weird conversions. In some cases I've had better luck with the encoding functions in [Microsoft Anti-XSS library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa973814), but not sure if this would work in your particular application.