# Missing Html Entities decoding support BY NAME in C# WPF for special letters/characters

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, html-entities

I have a problem decoding HTML entities. I have tried using both

```
System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode()
```

and in hopes that it was simply because this was a lightweight version of HttpUtilities, I've tried

```
HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()
```

as well.

My problem is that I need to decode from Entity names, not Entity Numbers.
(see this list http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp )

Both of the beforementioned methods decode to and from entity numbers, NOT entity names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont really see your problem. If I test the decoding via `WebUtility.HtmlDecode`, all entity names that are listed in the link you posted are decoded:

```
var encoded = "&quot;&apos;&amp;&lt;&gt;&iexcl;&cent;&pound;&curren;" +
              "&yen;&brvbar;&sect;&uml;&copy;&ordf;&laquo;&not;&shy;&reg;" +
              "&macr;&deg;&plusmn;&sup2;&sup3;&acute;&micro;&para;&middot;" +
              "&cedil;&sup1;&ordm;&raquo;&frac14;&frac12;&frac34;&iquest;" +
              "&times;&divide;&Agrave;&Aacute;&Acirc;&Atilde;&Auml;&Aring;" +
              "&AElig;&Ccedil;&Egrave;&Eacute;&Ecirc;&Euml;&Igrave;&Iacute;" +
              "&Icirc;&Iuml;&ETH;&Ntilde;&Ograve;&Oacute;&Ocirc;&Otilde;" +
              "&Ouml;&Oslash;&Ugrave;&Uacute;&Ucirc;&Uuml;&Yacute;&THORN;" +
              "&szlig;&agrave;&aacute;&acirc;&atilde;&auml;&aring;&aelig;" +
              "&ccedil;&egrave;&eacute;&ecirc;&euml;&igrave;&iacute;&icirc;" +
              "&iuml;&eth;&ntilde;&ograve;&oacute;&ocirc;&otilde;&ouml;" +
              "&oslash;&ugrave;&uacute;&ucirc;&uuml;&yacute;&thorn;&yuml;";
var expected = "\"'&<>¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿×÷ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓ" +
                "ÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ";

Console.WriteLine(System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(encoded) == expected);
```

This small snippet yields true.

When it comes to *encoding*: The `HtmlEncode` function is implemented to work just this way. There is little you can do about that, except from implementing it yourself, which I would not recommend (dont reinvent the wheel if you dont really need to). See also this SO question concerning the encoding: [C# HtmlEncode - ISO-8859-1 Entity Names vs Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853920/c-sharp-htmlencode-iso-8859-1-entity-names-vs-numbers)