# Search including swedish characters html-encoded

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

We’ve got an EF6 MVC3 codeFirst-site. Our news consist of two entities.
**newsPost** with the strings **Header** and **Introduction** and  **newsArticle** with the string **Body**, all nvarchar max in db.

In newsPost a swedish ö is stored as an ö in DB, but in newsArticle we have both ö and `&ouml;` stored (we’re using ckEditor for the editing the body).

When the user sends a string searchword it's easy to search for matches in the posts, but for the articles I would like to search for both the searchword and the html-encoded searchword.

I guess I want to write something like this

```
var htmlEncodedSearchword= Html.Encode(searchword);
var postIds = context.News.Where(m => m.Body.Contains(searchword)||m.Body.Contains(HtmlEncodedSearchword)).OrderByDescending(x=>x.PublicDate).Select(x => x.PostId).ToList();
```

...but I can’t figure out how to do.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method `WebUtility.HtmlEncode` which does that

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm almost there now,
It seems that CKeditor store the HTML-name ` &Ouml;` and HTMLencode gets me the  HTML-codes `&#214;`

Comment: it seems to be a problem see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853920/c-sharp-htmlencode-iso-8859-1-entity-names-vs-numbers)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Yes it seems to be harder than it should be.
I caved and made a couple of ugly replaces instead to take care of the most cases.