# How to get the HTML entity name from its entity number representation

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to get the HTML entity name from its number representation? I know that I can encode/decode strings by example:

```
   var decimalRep = "&#233";
   var fromDecimal= HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(decimalRep); //This will equal to è
```

How can I get the html entity name starting from `&#233` or even starting from `è` which should equal to `&egrave;`?

Comment: What do you mean with html entity name and it's decimal representation? Can you please explain a bit more in detail?

Comment: The string "& e grave;" is a way to represent è in html, how can I produce the string "& e grave;" from  the string "è" or from string "& # 233" in c#. Here is the list of the different representations and is from here where I got the "Entity Name" and decimal representation which is the same as "Entity Number" https://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html

Comment: You may need to follow the example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4853972/2030565. Create a table or switch to look up the character.